# Uploading multiple images in on element

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

I want to upload multiple images in one element. I keep getting a "You did not select a file upload" message. Here's what i've done so far;

My html form:

```
<?php
  echo form_open_multipart('properties/create_property_ajax'); ?>
     

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label">Price*</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" value="<?php echo                      set_value('price'); ?>" />
        <div class="form-error"><?php echo form_error('price'); ?></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-control-label">Upload Featured Image </label><br />
        <small>Only JPG and PNG files allowed (max 4MB).</small>
        <input type="file" name="featured_image[]" multiple="" class="form-control" accept=".jpeg,.jpg,.png" required />
        <div class="form-error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>
    </div>


<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

My Controller:

```
public function create_property_ajax()
{
    
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim|min_length[2]|max_length[800]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('state', 'State');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lga', 'LGA', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('amenities[]', 'Other Positions');

    //config for file uploads
    $config['upload_path']          = 'assets/uploads/properties'; //path to save the files
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG';  //extensions which are allowed
    $config['max_size']             = 1024 * 4; //filesize cannot exceed 4MB
    $config['file_ext_tolower']     = TRUE; //force file extension to lower case
    $config['remove_spaces']        = TRUE; //replace space in file names with underscores to avoid break
    $config['detect_mime']          = TRUE; //detect type of file to avoid code injection

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

        if ($_FILES['featured_image']['name'] == "") { //file is not selected
            $this->session->set_flashdata('status_msg_error', 'No file selected.');
            redirect(site_url('properties/new_property'));
        } elseif ((!$this->upload->do_upload('featured_image')) && ($_FILES['featured_image']['name'] != "")) {
            //upload does not happen when file is selected
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->new_property($error); //reload page with upload errors

        } else { //file is selected, upload happens, everyone is happy
            $featured_image = $this->upload->data('file_name');
            //generate thumbnail of the image with dimension 500x500
            $thumbnail = generate_image_thumb($featured_image, '500', '500');
            $this->property_model->add_new_property($featured_image,     $thumbnail);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('status_msg', 'Property added and published successfully.');
            redirect(site_url('properties'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->new_property(); //validation fails, reload page with validation errors
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
public function add_new_property($featured_image, $thumbnail)
{
    $title = ucwords($this->input->post('title', TRUE));
    $description = $this->input->post('description', TRUE);
    $price = $this->input->post('price', TRUE);
    $state = ucwords($this->input->post('state', TRUE));
    $lga = $this->input->post('lga', TRUE);
    $address = $this->input->post('address', TRUE);
    $amenities = implode(", ", $this->input->post('amenities', TRUE));

    $data = array(
        'title' => $title,
        'description' => $description,
        'price' => $price,
        'state' => $state,
        'lga' => $lga,
        'address' => $address,
        'amenities' => $amenities,
        'featured_image' => $featured_image,
        'featured_image_thumb' => $thumbnail,
    );
    $this->db->insert('property', $data);
}
```

My goal is to be able to upload multiple images in one element or in one row in the database. Please can anyone help point out the issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```html
$this->load->library('upload');
    
$upload_config = array();
$upload_config['upload_path'] = 'assets/uploads/properties';
$upload_config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|gif|jpeg|png'; 

$array_images_uplaoded = array();
$files = $_FILES;
$multi_file = count($_FILES['featured_image']['name']);
for($i=0; $i<$multi_file; $i++)
{           
    $_FILES['featured_image']['name']= $files['featured_image']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['featured_image']['type']= $files['featured_image']['type'][$i];    

    $this->upload->initialize($upload_config);
    $this->upload->do_upload('featured_image');
    $array_images_uplaoded[] = $this->upload->data();
}

print_r($array_images_uplaoded); // uploaded images
```